# Customize AutoHotkey Syntax Highlighting for UltraEdit?

Tags: autohotkey, ultraedit

I am using UltraEdit for writing/editing my AutoHotkey scripts. To enjoy of syntax highlighting for AutoHotkey scripts in UltraEdit I have installed "Run this to install syntax highlighting for UltraEdit.ahk" which comes together with AutoHotkey installation. The issue is that I don't like the way 'comments' and 'strings' are formatted in Italic.

How do you change format and AutoHotkey syntax highlighting for UltraEdit; particularly for 'comments' and 'strings' so that they are shown in Normal font style (non-italic) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change the colors in UltraEdit (scroll down to "Manage Themes - Syntax") :**
http://www.ultraedit.com/help/article/manage-themes-5320.html

**from the mentioned script:**

```
SyntaxFileNameList = CommandNames|Keywords|Variables|Functions|Keys|Operators|Separators|Special
;Default colors in UE:  blue     |red     |orange   |green    |brown|blue    |blue      |blue
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **Joe DF** for providing this useful link :
[Manage Themes for UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/help/article/manage-themes-5320.html)

To change font style for the theme elements (e.g. Comments or Strings), open **Manage Themes** window through the menu : 
**View -> Themes -> Manage Themes...**
On the tap page **Syntax** you can change color and font style for each theme element.

P.S. I am using UltraEdit v21; however you should find window Manage Themes easily if you have the older versions.

Comment: someone said nice fork there and that's true ;)